# Make HTML5 Canvas area unselectable without Javascript

Tags: css, html, canvas

An app I am making has tabs that use an HTML5 canvas as a backing (they are rounded like chrome tabs, which can't be done through border radius or conventional HTML). However, when someone double clicks on things around the tabs, it highlights the entire canvas area.

```
// i've tried:
canvas { outline: none; }

// and
canvas { -moz-user-select: none /* etc */ }

// to no avail.
```

The only solutions I can find on the web is to use JS and event bind each damn canvas with things like:

```
canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
```

Then we have to get into unbinding events, etc. etc. and I have these tabs all over my app.

#### Is there any one shot solution so I don't have to get into this?

#### UPDATE

To humor CBroe:

[image]

and the problem:

[image]

#### SOLVED

pbebbl solved it, by calling a user-select: none on the parent element of the canvas.

Comment: Can you show a minimal working example of the problem (either in a code block in the question, or on JSFiddle)? It always helps to show exactly what's going on for people to be able to help you.

Comment: _“(they are rounded like chrome tabs, which can't be done through border radius or conventional HTML)”_ – got an example of that?

Comment: There you go. Unless you wanted the canvas JS as well....

Comment: For those using BabylonJS what worked for me was the CSS `canvas { outline: none; }`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need to support IE9, then you can indeed use user-select (you'll need prefixes for each of the browsers: -ms-, -moz-, and -webkit-).
It's possible the reason that the selection is still appearing is that a higher-level element than you think is selected. Example:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="richUI">
            <canvas id="navigationTabs">
```

If you're doing it to "navigationTabs", try it for "richUI" - or higher.

Comment: Hmmm. In Firefox, (with firebug), I set `canvas { -moz-user-select: none; }`, and this did not do the trick. To verify the canvas was the element, I deleted it, and indeed no highlighting occurred on the tab.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your set up but you could try `pointer-events` — it's only supported in the more recent of browsers however:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

```
canvas { pointer-events: none; }
```

Obviously this will cause problems if your expecting to trap any mouse events directly on the canvas layers themselves.

#### update

Hmm. Well it really depends on your markup to what different things you could try, if you posted some of that into your answer it would help. Another guess, which would specifically target the issue which is to block the `ondblclick` event — but that wouldn't prevent selections occuring by other means.

```
<body ondblclick="return false">
```

Also with regard to @Katana314's answer, you may need to disable the selection on the element that wraps the canvas element, rather than target the canvas element directly, for example:

```
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
  <canvas />
</div>
```

And then use:

```
.canvas-wrapper { -moz-user-select: none; }
```

That may work.

Comment: This got me excited for a second, but it didn't do the trick :(

Comment: See, it highlights when I double click on an element near it, like this: double click near a paragraph on SO, and the whole paragraph highlights. Same concept.

Comment: @dc2 Ah ok, that's a shame, well was just a guess :) -- I've updated my answer with a couple more. Actually the `.canvas-wrapper` approach I mention may also work for `pointer-event` too. Worth a try at least anyway.

Comment: +1 for your effort. Let me try these things out - i'll let you know.

Comment: You did it - `.canvas-wrapper { -moz-user-select: none; }` nailed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @dc2 no worries :) -- I'd recommend an up vote for Katana314 (even marking their answer as accepted) as they came up with the correct solution first; it was just an implementation wrangle that prevented it from working. Glad it helped though.